# Editable Word Document from JSP

Tags: jsp, ms-word, edit

Is there a way to create a link in a JSP page to a Microsoft Word document that you can edit and have it post back automatically to the server? 
I'm using Websphere Portal.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/). I believe Microsoft Word understands how to read and save documents from WebDAV servers. You would need to implement a WebDAV server for this to be possible but I'm sure there are a variety of open-source implementations available - a quick Google turns up [this one](http://webdav-servlet.sourceforge.net/) which looks quite interesting.